# mvc poco list is null: add new item

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, collections, poco

I have the following POCO in my MVC4 project:

```
public class Gallery : ModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
    public string ThumbnailPath { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public ICollection<GalleryImage> Images { get; set; }
}
```

If I create a new Gallery entity, the Images Collection is null. How can I add a new Image (in my case) to the uninitialized list?
My code for adding looks like this:

```
Guid gGallery = Guid.Parse(Request.Form.GetValues("galleryId")[0]);
            Gallery gallery = db.Galleries.Where(g => g.Id == gGallery).Include(g => g.Images).First();

            galleryimage.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            galleryimage.CreatedByUserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
            galleryimage.InsertDate = DateTime.Now;
            galleryimage.LastModDate = DateTime.Now;

            db.GalleryImages.Add(galleryimage);
            if (gallery.Images == null)
                gallery.Images = new List<GalleryImage>();
            gallery.Images.Add(galleryimage);

            db.SaveChanges();
```

The code breaks at runtime with this exception (Sorry only in german):

> Ein Objekt vom Typ 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[gallery.Models.GalleryImage, gallery, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' kann für eine EntityReference vom Typ 'gallery.Models.GalleryImage' nicht als Value-Eigenschaft festgelegt oder daraus entfernt werden.

Now how can I add a new item to an uninitialized collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in your POCO and should be as follows:

```
public class Gallery : ModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
    public string ThumbnailPath { get; set; }

    // remove the ForeignKey attr. That should be in GalleryImage itself
    public ICollection<GalleryImage> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have many problems in your code.

First you should use `Guid.TryParse` or validate that Guid is a valid Guid.

Then you should use `Request.Form.GetValues("galleryId")[0]` which you can get a NPE.

Moreover, you should avoid using `First()`, you should use `FirstOrDefault` and be more defensive, is: check if that is null or not.

And yet, you have more problems, once you load the Gallery, you can add the gallery image to Images and then call db.savechanges();

Comment: Thanks a lot! Removing the attribute solved the problem. I've also implemented your additional Tips though TryParse for the GUID would not be necessary as I've created a constraint on the controller action in my routes config which already validates the guids.